# Display a message when nothing matches (Js / Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

For an internship project I used Ajax for the first time, I succeeded in creating a function allowing to do a search and to display only the names resulting from this research. My problem is that when I enter the beginning or a name that is not in the database nothing append (logic) and I would like to know how to simply display an error message from the type "No users matched your search" or something like that rather than show all.

My code:

```html
  <script>
$('#testlf').submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    test2();
})
function test2(){

console.log($("#submitlf").val());
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'fonctions/recherche_utilisateurs.php',
        data: 'mdl_user=' + $("#submitlf").val(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data !=""){
                $('#globalitem > *').remove();
                $('#globalitem').prepend(data);
            }else{
                document.getElementById('result-search').innerHTML = "<div> Aucun Utilisateur </div>"
            }
        }

    });

}
  </script>
```

second page :

```html
if(isset($_GET['mdl_user'])) {
    $user = (string)trim($GET['mdl_user']);
    $a = $_GET['mdl_user'];

    $q = $DB->get_records_sql(
        "SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname, institution FROM mdl_user, mdl_role_assignments WHERE (firstname LIKE '%".$a."%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$a."%') AND (mdl_role_assignments.id = mdl_user.id AND mdl_role_assignments.roleid = 4)",
        array("%$user%"));



// affichage du résultat

    foreach ($q as $item) {
        echo '
         <div class="listforma" style="border : 1px solid black" >
         <div class="photolf"> <img  alt="test" src="'. new moodle_url('/user/pix.php/'.$USER->id.'/f1.jpg').'" > </img>  </div>
        <div class="textlf">
        <div class="nomprenomlf"> ' . $item->firstname . ', ' . $item->lastname . ' </div>

        <div class="formationlf"> ' . $item->institution.' </div>
            <br>  <br>  <br>
                 <div class="complf">   '.$item->institution.'   </div>
         <div class="boxlf ">
             <div class="pilf">  <a href="" style="color: #6E706E"> Prochaines interventions    ></a> </div>
             <div class="travauxlf">  <a href="" style="color: #6E706E"> Travaux inter-sessions  > </a> </div>
             <div class="evalf">  <a href="" style="color: #6E706E"> Évaluation de satisfaction  ></a> </div>



         </div>


        </div>
    </div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see how this could display “everything”, when you enter a name that does not exist - the part of your WHERE condition that checks inside the first- and lastname fields should never be true then.

Comment: _“when I enter the beginning”_ - if you enter `a`, then it will of course find all records, where the first- or lastname have an `a` _anywhere_ in them. If(?) you want to limit this to only names that _start_ with `a` - then the `%` before the search term would need to be removed.

Comment: And FYI, it appears you are not correctly using prepared statements there to begin with, so this is vulnerable to SQL injection. (You are passing `array("%$user%")` to the method, but you are not using any placeholders inside the query, but have concatenated `$a` into the SQL statement directly.)

Comment: Thx for your answer and yeah i was wrong just nothing happend when the name does not exist so i just wanted to know what should i add to have an "error message" when nothing is found

Comment: Your database class should probably provide a method to check how many records the result set contains, so go look for that, and then implement an if/else to do your foreach loop if you got more than 0 records, and output an error message otherwise.

Comment: Do you know how am i supposed to do that ? Cause i don't have any idea to how to do this

Comment: Which part - read the documentation of whatever class you are using there, or implement a simple if/else?

Comment: ouch anyways thx for your help

Comment: Maybe try this  `if(count($q)){ foreach...}else{echo '';}`